# Phaser 3 : sprite movement like Endless Sky NPC

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, phaser-framework

I'm trying to replicate the NPC movement in [Endless Sky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pia0nGTl15o). Checkout [Endless Sky Github's Repository](https://github.com/endless-sky/endless-sky) using [Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/phaser3).

The characteristic of the NPC is that they have drag and rotate to face the direction they intend to travel. I can do this with the player character using

```
player.body.setAngularVelocity(0);
player.body.setAcceleration(0)
scene.physics.velocityFromAngle(player.angle - 90, 400, player.body.acceleration)
```

But I can't seem to get it right with an npc - and by "get it right" I mean a smooth movement of the sprite turning/tweening to face the new coordinates and then moving towards it.

The closest I had was the sprite seemed to be moving correctly but the image/texture of the sprite was frantically changing angle, sometimes doing a 360 rotation. Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the body.angle / body.rotation as well as the math involved?

At the moment, I am passing the npc a random vector to travel to:

```
 enemy.stateMachine.transition('patrolling', [Phaser.Math.Between(-3500, 3500), Phaser.Math.Between(-3500, 3000)])
```

`-3500` and `3000` being the bounds of my game world.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "can't seem to get it right"? Is there an error message? Or is the NPC not moving the way you would expected it? Or not moving at all, or..?

Comment: good question. I have updated my original question. Hopefully, that clarifies.